# Import Agribalyse3.1.bw2package in Brightway failed. OSError: Invalid data stream

Tags: python, brightway

I am new to brightway and looking for help.
The error I got is "OSError: Invalid data stream" when importing the new Agribalyse3.1.

Previously I imported ecoinvent3.9 with no errors.
I followed these instructions: https://github.com/sc-gcoste/brightway-agribalyse3.1/blob/master/exploring_agb3.1.ipynb

Where is my error?

```
import brightway2 as bw
import os

bw.projects.set_current('Importing agribalyse3.1')
bw.bw2setup()
print(os.listdir('../data/'))
path ='../data/AGB31.bw2package'
bw.BW2Package.import_file(path)
```

Output:

```
Biosphere database already present!!! No setup is needed
['AGB31.bw2package']
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [5], line 4
      2 print(os.listdir('../data/'))
      3 path ='../data/AGB31.bw2package'
----> 4 bw.BW2Package.import_file(path)

File c:\Users\Pro\anaconda3\envs\ab_dev\lib\site-packages\bw2io\package.py:198, in BW2Package.import_file(cls, filepath, whitelist)
    186 @classmethod
    187 def import_file(cls, filepath, whitelist=True):
    188     """Import bw2package file, and create the loaded objects, including registering, writing, and processing the created objects.
    189 
    190     Args:
   (...)
    196 
    197     """
--> 198     loaded = cls.load_file(filepath, whitelist)
    199     with warnings.catch_warnings():
    200         warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

File c:\Users\Pro\anaconda3\envs\ab_dev\lib\site-packages\bw2io\package.py:180, in BW2Package.load_file(cls, filepath, whitelist)
    168 @classmethod
    169 def load_file(cls, filepath, whitelist=True):
    170     """Load a bw2package file with one or more objects. Does not create new objects.
    171 
...
--> 103     data = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock, size)
    104 if data:
    105     break

OSError: Invalid data stream
```

Comment: Data source: https://doc.agribalyse.fr/documentation-en/agribalyse-data/data-about-food

Comment: Git Issue: https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/issues/148

Comment: See Git issue for further information. With a SimaPro Export it worked.